# how test a value in try except block with pytest and coverage in django setting?

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, code-coverage

I would like to test a Try/Except block, but I try any method Coverage that says that part is not tested. My goal is to test the Error_Message from the user's django settings, and if the user did not define file_validator_error_message in his Django settings, I would like to consider a default value (file} is not valid). Now I want to test the ERROR_MESSAGE value in the area where I test the Attributeerror error but I don't know how? The point is that in line 10 Coverage says: **line 10 didn't jump to line 11, because the exception caught by line 10 didn't happen**

[image]

**code :**

```
try:
    # Get Error Message From Django Setting
    ERROR_MESSAGE = settings.FILE_VALIDATOR_ERROR_MESSAGE
except AttributeError:
    ERROR_MESSAGE = "{file} is not valid"
except ImproperlyConfigured:
    ERROR_MESSAGE = "{file} is not valid"
```

I want to test the ERROR_MESSAGE value in the AttributeerRor error section

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my code as follows and the problem was fixed :

```
try:
    # Get Error Message From Django Setting
    CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE = settings.FILE_VALIDATOR_ERROR_MESSAGE
except (AttributeError, ImproperlyConfigured):
    CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE = "{file} is not valid"
```